# SUP/SUB tag in XML

Tags: html, xml, dtd

Can i use Superscript and Subscript tags in XML file?

I tried copy pasting,using `<SUP>` tags but it is giving error .I have also searched a lot,but could not get proper solution.

Could anyone please suggest me solution?

Comment: Provide your XML. May be it has reference to schema.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>title</string>
  <key>subchapters</key>
    <string>name</string>
  
 </dict>
 
 </array>
</plist>

Comment: My supposition was correct. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788711/sup-sub-tag-in-xml/6789427#6789427

Comment: What technology do you use for parsing?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the XML standard that precludes `SUP` or `SUB` elements.

However, they don't have any specific meaning in XML either.

If you expect them to show up as super and sub scripts, this will not happen.

Comment: Can we write those tags in Plist?Actually i want to display that in plist and that is in XML format.So is there and solution to display in plist?
Can you please tell me what is the difference between XML and Plist?
Waiting for your reply?

Comment: @shradha - You never mentioned a schema/DTD in your original question. If you look at it, [here](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd), you will see that these are not supported elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any tags you like in XML, that's the whole point of it.

Please never use the phrase "I tried it and it gave me an error" without telling us what the error was. We like to be helpful but we can't explain an error for you without seeing the error message. It's like telling your doctor you don't feel well without telling him the symptoms.

Comment: i have used   <string>h<sub>2</sub>o</string> 
but it gave me error as " unexpected character s at line11"

Answer (score 1):

This XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>title</string>

            <key>subchapters</key>
            <string>name</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

has reference to DTD in which element `sub` is not defined. This DTD is located http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

I think you can omit DTD validation in your XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text in a CDATA tag, like so:

```
<![CDATA[ <string>haii</string> ]]>
```

The XML parser will not try to parse the content inside, but interpret it as a literal, which will solve your problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<array>

<dict>

<key>name</key>
<string>Chapter name</string>
<key>subchapters</key>
<array/>

</dict>

</array>

</plist>

Comment: I want to write H<sub>2</sub>o or content like M<sup>2</sup> in place of 'chapter name'. But could not do so.